# Getting ModuleNotFoundError in Conda environment even after package installation

Tags: python, pip, conda

I have Python 3.6 with my Anaconda env. The `h2o` package is already installed as shown below but still getting error while importing it.

[image: Package installed as per Anaconda GUI]

[image: Installation confirmation from the notebook]

As shown in the above snapshots, no module found error appears! Any ideas what is going wrong?

Comment: Anaconda uses conda environment instead pip. Try using conda install h2o before import the package and look if it solves your problem.

Comment: Also check if the h2o is installed on base (root) too.. Perhaps you're running the Jupyter from the base root, and it will not find the h2o on python36 environment.

Comment: Is the notebook using the correct Python installation? As an aside, please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Comment: Using the command '!conda install h2o h2o-py' is throwing me an error 'PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:'. However, I was able to do this installation in my env using the Anaconda GUI.  My base env is having py 3.7 and I had to create a new env with py 3.6 for this H2o installation. I have specifically selected my new py 3.6 env 'python36' for running this H2o command. Do you think still my kernel is looking into base env where I have py 3.7 and no H2o installed? If so, how can I fix it